# How can I select the dynamic column in SELECT statement using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

Sorry my English is very poor so I just can describe my problem very meager
I have used OPENROWSET to get a raw data table from an excel file as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\PP.xlsx',
                'SELECT * FROM [Daily$]')
```

[enter image description here][image: 1]

The problems is each column is a dynamically date which user who created the Excel file update it every day.

So I need a solution to select the column= current date (or any date).
Hopefully you can understand my point, below is my code:

```
Select 
    t1.*, temp.[13-Nov] as [Plan]
from 
    (select 
         case 
            when FinalMaterial = 'IA15_2020' then 'FADIL'
            when FinalMaterial = 'ID2U_2020' then 'V8'
            when FinalMaterial = 'ID1U_2019' then 'SUV'
            when FinalMaterial = 'ID14_2019' then 'Sedan'
            else FinalMaterial 
         end FinalMaterial,
         case 
            when statusto in ('TP_40', 'TP_40B') then 'Paint' 
            when statusto = 'TP_20' then 'Body'
            when statusto = 'TP_80' then 'OKTS'
            when statusto = 'TP_F1' then 'F1 out'
            else null 
         end Shop,
         count(WorkOrder_NId) Actual
     from 
         vLogicalStatusTrans_1138772611 lo 
     join 
         vWorkOrder_Siemens__1008010152 wo on wo.NId = lo.WorkOrder_NId
     where 
         StatusTo in ('TP_40', 'TP_40B', 'TP_20', 'TP_80', 'TP_F1')
         and dateadd(hh, 7, lo.TransitionTime) >= SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 00, 00)
     group by 
         wo.FinalMaterial, statusto) t1
left join 
    (select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\PP.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Daily$]')) as temp on temp.Model = t1.FinalMaterial and temp.Shop = t1.Shop
where 
    t1.Shop = 'Paint'
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `select` field list on the fly means constructing a "dynamic query" where your build the entire query in a string variable (`nvarchar` type) and pass that to a stored procedure like `sp_executesql` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)).

**Sample data**

```
create table exceldata
(
  id int,
  [14-nov] int,
  [15-nov] int,
  [16-nov] int
);

insert into exceldata (id, [14-nov], [15-nov], [16-nov]) values
(1, 114, 115, 116),
(2, 214, 215, 216);
```

**Solution**

```
declare @today date = getdate();

declare @stmt nvarchar(500) =   'select id, ['
                              + replace(convert(nvarchar(6),  @today, 106), ' ', '-')
                              + '] from exceldata;'

select @stmt as Statement; -- validation

exec sp_executesql @stmt;
```

**Result**

For `@today = '2020-11-14'`:

```
Statement
-----------------------------------
select id, [14-Nov] from exceldata;

id  14-Nov
--- ------
1   114
2   214
```

For `@today = '2020-11-15'`:

```
Statement
-----------------------------------
select id, [15-Nov] from exceldata;

id  15-Nov
--- ------
1   115
2   215
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=188223626f9eb77782f6aa4109dc019e) to see it in action (includes step by step date format construction).